# Configuring git push/commit to not push/show submodule updates

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I am working on a project that has numerous submodules. Here is the gist of how the project is structured:

```
Bundle Repo
-- Submodule A
-- Submodule B
-- Submodule C
-- Submodule D
-- Submodule E
-- src

Submodule A
-- src
Submodule B
-- src
//...and so forth for the rest of the submodules
```

Here is the .gitmodules file (as an example) in the bundle repo:

```
[submodule "submodule_a"]
    path = submodule_a
    url = *some url*
    branch = dev
    ignore = dirty
[submodule "submodule_b"]
    path = submodule_b
    url = *some url*
    branch = dev
    ignore = dirty
//...and so forth for the rest of the submodules
```

The bundle project involves the various submodule projects working/interacting with each other, so when a developer is working with the bundle project, we ensure that the submodules are all properly updated using the command: `git submodule update --remote --recursive`.

This updates the submodules to the latest commit on the 'dev' branch (as seen in the example .gitmodules file above). However, the issue is when the developer is monitoring their changes in the bundle's src files (we never make changes in projects through submodules. we will directly work in that submodule's repository instead), the 'updates' that are pulled when updating the submodules are listed as non-committed changes.

I want to remove that. There are two things that could be done:

1) Since every developer on the project knows to update submodules prior to working/testing in the bundle repository, we do not need to push the submodule updates (pointing to the latest commit) whenever we push to the bundle. Is there a way to disable the submodule updates showing up as non-committed changes?

2) Is there a way inside git itself (we are using gitlab for our service) to automatically have the bundle repo update itself to point to the latest commit whenever a submodule repo has a new commit?

Hope this isn't too confusing. Thanks!